# Django-rest как присвоить id анонимному пользователю

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Есть модель django. Через Drf создаю/изменяю записи. В сериализаторе использую ModelSerializer.
Есть задача что бы анонимный(неавторизованый) пользователь, мог создавать записи и ему присваивался уникальный id. Как присвоить id анониму на уровне сериализатора?

Answer (score 2):

На постоянной основе никак. А так - генерируете `guid` (`uiid.uiid4().hex` ) и кладете в сессию/куки. Если нужен `id` (число), то лучше в сессию, чтобы нельзя было изменить в ручную в куках

Присвоить объекту анонима можно в `middleware`, смотрите, если юзер - аноним, то к его объекту `AnonimousUser` можете дописать `id` / `guid`